# response.sendError throws exception with custom filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, servlet-filters

I have a signup form that upon submit I need to:
Create a new user and signin the user.

If the username is already in the database I need to return 409 with error message.

I've created a custom filter which sets the HttpStatus

```
public class UserSignupFilter implements Filter {
...
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        if (userSignup(request)) {
            if (userAlreadyExists(request)){
                logger.info("Didnt create user since: "+e.getMessage());
                response.sendError(HttpStatus.CONFLICT.value());
            } else {
                createUser(request);
            }
        }           
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I am getting sometimes:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed.
```

Is there a better way to do it?
I am setting my security programmatically (Spring Security V 3.2) how can I use ExceptionTranslationFilter?

Comment: Do you have any other filters in the chain? Note that you should `return` immediately after `sendError`. `doFilter` shouldn't need to be called if you already committed the response.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Is there a way to accept a comment? anyway thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should be calling:

```
chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

If all you want to do is send error code back. Just call return

```
logger.info("Didnt create user since: "+e.getMessage());
response.sendError(HttpStatus.CONFLICT.value());
return;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `ExceptionTranslationFilter` you need to throw an exception (not commit the response). As long as your filter is downstream if the security filter that should do it, or else put your filter in the security filter chain after the exception translation filter.